# GCP PUB/SUB io.grpc.StatusException CANCELLED

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-pubsub

We are getting below error for the gcp pub/sub subscription. What could be the cause here and in which case this method getting triggered.

io.grpc.Status.asException(Status.java:541)
at com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.StreamingSubscriberConnection.doStop(StreamingSubscriberConnection.java:139)
at  com.google.api.core.AbstractApiService$InnerService.doStop(AbstractApiService.java:153)
at  com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractService.stopAsync(AbstractService.java:281)
at  com.google.api.core.AbstractApiService.stopAsync(AbstractApiService.java:129)
at  com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.Subscriber.stopConnections(Subscriber.java:394)
at  com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.Subscriber.stopAllStreamingConnections(Subscriber.java:367)
at  com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.Subscriber.access$1700(Subscriber.java:93)
at  com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.Subscriber$3.run(Subscriber.java:308)
at  java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)`your text`

As per pub/sub open api jar this method supposed to get triggered in case subscription is getting expired and its trying to clean.

Comment: It would be helpful to see your code. This method should only get triggered if you explicitly shut down the subscriber or there is a permanent error in starting up the subscriber. Also, does the error always happen when you run the subscriber? Do you successfully receive any messages?